# How to remove cycles from a directed graph

Tags: graphs

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284469/how-to-remove-cycles-in-an-unweighted-directed-graph-such-that-the-number-of-ed) from SO which led to [Feedback Arc Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set), which describes the problem nicely:

> In graph theory, a directed graph may contain directed cycles, a one-way loop of edges. In some applications, such cycles are undesirable, and we wish to eliminate them and obtain a directed acyclic graph (DAG).

I am wondering how this is done. Given a graph such as this:

```
a -> b
b -> c
c -> d
d -> a
```

Or a for loop flattened out such as:

```
somemethod -> forloop start
forloop start -> forloop next
forloop next -> forloop result
forloop next -> forloop next // i+1
forloop next -> forloop end
forloop end -> forloop result
forloop result -> next method
```

Wondering how you can possibly remove the cycles from a graph like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a paper "breaking cycles in noisy hierarchies" which talks about leveraging graph hierarchy to delete cycle edges to reduce a directed graph to a DAG.

The reduced DAG will maintain the graph hierarchy of the original graph as much as possible.

The corresponding code is available on Github: https://github.com/zhenv5/breaking_cycles_in_noisy_hierarchies

Answer (score 2):

You can always make a digraph acyclic by removing all edges. The goal in feedback arc set is to remove the minimum number of edges, or in the weighted case, to minimize the total weight of edges removed. In your case, you can make the graph acyclic by removing any of the edges.

Comment: Didn't realize it was that simple. Was thinking maybe (for the for loop) you would specify a maximum bound and then do `iteration1 -> iteration2 -> iteration3 ... iterationBound -> next method`. Wondering if there's any tricks like that to turn things acyclic. For `a-b-c-d-a`, I can't think of anything other than what you're suggesting.

Comment: Wondering if there is a field of research studying the example expansion: `iteration1 -> iteration2 -> iteration3 ... iterationBound` "expanding directed cycles into flat lists"

Comment: It's usually called "loop unrolling".